# What is the difference between style- and onEachFeature function reading *geojson file

Tags: leaflet, styles, geojson

I read a *.geojson file with

```
$.ajax(overlay).done(function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: pointToLayer,
            style: style,
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    });
return});
```

As far as I understand (newbie), for each marker in the file the pointToLayer -function is processed, for each polygon and linestring the style-function AND the onEachFeature-function. Right?
What is the difference between the last two functions (not considering the name)?

Gruss, wonk

Comment: What is the purpose of `return` in the end?

Answer (score 2):

- The `pointToLayer` callback function runs on all `Point` GeoJSON features, then
- the `style` function runs on all `LineString` and `Polygon` GeoJSON features, then
- the `onEachFeature` callback function runs on **both** points (now `L.Marker`s) **and** linestrings/polygons (now `L.Polyline`s and `L.Polygon`s).

Note that `pointToLayer` and `style` take a GeoJSON feature as input, whereas `onEachFeature` takes the instance of `L.Layer` as well. That `L.Layer` can come from **either** the `pointToLayer` callback or internally with the information from the `style` callback.

Comment: Sorry, the "return" should be omitted.